Can you share a single connection pool across all java programs running on a host?
As per our design, we will create a VM host and we will have multiple Java programs that will run on that host. Each program will read from a table in the Oracle database and write to a different database (as per config). The source Oracle database will be the same for all jobs and only the table name would differ.
I'm wondering if it's possible to use connection pooling here so that all Java programs running on that VM host would be able to share connections from a single pool. This would reduce a lot of connection creation time and resources.
I checked online but I'm not able to find any solution which helps here. All are for connection pooling in a single program. But I need to share that pool across multiple programs.

You cannot share resources between different java processes.

one solution for your challenge is create one application that will hold all database connections and rules that will serve all applications that will consume that application holds database rules and connections ( I don't see advantages to do that but is a solution )

I think it's theoretically possible if you create all connections before starting all other VMs, but so vastly complicated that it would involve class manipulation at the bytecode level. Probably not what you want.

@JohnBayko No it isn’t. Connections belong to processes and cannot be shared,

@user207421 They are inherited. So if a VM forks another VM, the connections are inherited, but not accessible without some other way to communicate their existence. That can be done with several IPC mechanisms (even command arguments) but then you would need to construct the Java objects from the relevant classes to access them (similar to how PowerMock works). I don't think it's practical, which is why I said theoretical.
